# Simple Regex in Python Three to replace text between '|' and '/' symbols

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace the text between the '|' and '/' in the string ("|伊士曼柯达公司/") with '!!!'.

```
s = '柯達⑀柯达⑀ /Kodak (brand, US film company)/full name Eastman Kodak Company 伊士曼柯達公司|伊士曼柯达公司/'
print(s)
s = re.sub(r'\|.*?\/.', '/!!!', s)
print('\t', s)
```

I tested the code first on https://regex101.com/, and it worked perfectly.

I can't quite figure out why it's not doing the replacement in python.

Variant's of escaping I've tried also include:

```
s = re.sub(r'|.*?\/.', '!!!', s)
s = re.sub(r'|.*?/.', '!!!', s)
s = re.sub(r'\|.*?/.', '!!!', s)
```

Each time the string comes out unchanged.

Comment: I don't see `|` in your text.

Comment: change this \|.*?\/.   to   \|.*?\/    without dot at the end

Comment: @MohammedElhag It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can change your regex to this one, which uses lookarounds to ensure what you want to replace is preceded by `|` and followed by `/`

```
(?<=\|).*?(?=/)
```

Check this Python code,

```
import re

s = '柯達⑀柯达⑀ /Kodak (brand, US film company)/full name Eastman Kodak Company 伊士曼柯達公司|伊士曼柯达公司/'
print(s)
s = re.sub(r'(?<=\|).*?(?=/)', '!!!', s)
print(s)
```

Prints like you expect,

```
柯達⑀柯达⑀ /Kodak (brand, US film company)/full name Eastman Kodak Company 伊士曼柯達公司|伊士曼柯达公司/
柯達⑀柯达⑀ /Kodak (brand, US film company)/full name Eastman Kodak Company 伊士曼柯達公司|!!!/
```

**[Online Python Demo](https://rextester.com/HOWAES65824)**